# Why do the following ruby codes show race conditions despite GVL?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading many articles about GVL and trying to understand what it does.

My current understanding is:

- GVL is a sort-of global Mutex to allow only one native thread to execute ruby codes.
- Only the thread that holds GVL can execute ruby codes
- However, if a thread that holds GVL does I/O things, the thread releases  GVL so that another thread acquires GVL resulting in running concurrently.

Therefore, if I wrote codes that do not contain any I/O operation, I can safely assume there is no race condition due to concurrency.

Having written the following codes, I noticed that the variable `to` exceeded `10000000`(initial `from.` value) to some extent.

```rb
from = 100000000
to = 0

50.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    while from > 0
      from -= 1
      to += 1
    end
  end
end.map(&:join)

puts "from: #{from}"
puts "to: #{to}"
```

`to` always results `100000000` by inserting Mutex into that code, but why is that happen?
As of my understanding, the condition `while from > 0` is evaluated by only one thread thanks to GVL at the same time, and there should not be such race conditions.

[image]

I expected the result like

```
from: 0
to: 10000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GVL is not only released when a thread does IO.

Imagine a thread not doing any IO at all, then the other threads would never get a chance if GVL was only released on IO.

Instead, it is entirely possible that a thread has to wait for other threads after any atomic operation. For example, directly after checking the `while from > 0` condition or between `from -= 1` and `to += 1`.

And it is worth noting that `to += 1` is not even an atomic operation. It is a shortcut for `to = to + 1` and it can be interrupted between evaluating the right side and setting the new value.

When you really need thread safety, then you need to implement mutexs or semaphores.

Comment: Oh, I finally got to understand.
 I also understood that it is required to use Mutex or memory barrier as I do in other languages, even if there is GVL in Ruby. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because of the GVL, there will only be one thread at a time running in the same process. So, no threads in parallel within one process. But sequentially there can be many threads and they can be interrupted, paused and continued at any time and between almost every command in the code.

Comment: A small thing to add here. GVL only prevents 2 threads from running RUBY code in parallel. Many basic features are implemented in C and when one thread enters a C implementation of a method, another thread can execute ruby code.

In the current case, for example even `to + 1` is implemented in C and should release GVL.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Slim. What you pointed out was completely out of my consideration and I didn't even imagine!!!

I came to understand that relying on GVL for syncing concurrent operations may result in unsound results as it forces us to check whether the implementation we use comes from C or Ruby.